# c++ template class bubble sort operand error

Tags: c++, sorting, templates

Hi i trying to create a template method to sort a vector of object by their x coordinate. They are giving me operand error with the '=' sign

Inside main have some codes, vector point2d have already data being populated.

```
vector<Point2D> point2d;
.....
point2d = sortByAscX(point2d, point2d.size());
```

my template.h

```
template <class T>
vector<T> sortByAscX(vector<T> a1, int size) { 

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++) {

        for(int y=0; y<size-1; y++) {

            if(a1[y].getX()<a1[y+1].getX()) {

                int temp = a1[y+1].getX();

                a1[y+1].setX(a1[y].getX());

                a1[y].setX(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return a1;    
}
```

Error

```
MyTemplates.h:32:20: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     a1[y+1].getX() = a1[y].getX();
                    ^
MyTemplates.h:34:18: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     a1[y].getX() = temp;
```

Comment: getX() returns a value. you're assigning a literal to yet another literal.

Comment: I tried changing to set value but it come out 0

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is that you are calling a `getX()` function and trying to set it equal to a value. You need to have or call a `setX()` function and pass your value through it. You can only get a value with a get function.

Comment: i tried doing this and it produce 0 
int temp = a1[y+1].getX();

a1[y+1].setX(a1[y].getX());

a1[y].setX(temp);

Comment: What do you mean it produced 0. In the code you have it looks like you are trying to swap the X values of 2 elements of a vector. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

As @NendoTaka correctly explained, you are trying to assign to a rvalue. If you want to use the same function for both a getter/setter, then make it return a reference

```
T& getX() { ...}
```

although now the name will be a tad confusing, as most people expect the getter to return an non-mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

What does getX() return?  It must not be an assignable value because that is what the compiler is complaining about.  If it returns a reference of the X value, you can assign to it, but if it is const or returns a copy you can't assign to it.